# Keyboard constant push not responding, possibly cause by lwjgl

Tags: lwjgl

Well, though this is a developers question and answer site, and i'm not, but i haven't found answer nowhere, i'll kindly ask to you for it..

I'm using a overhaul mod for minecraft and today i've bought a new keyboard, the fact is that i have to heavily push the button to advance or the space bar for example to keep registring their use, if i loosen the strength they stop registring, one of the developers of the mods hinted to me that the cause might be lwjgl since "thats what the library MC uses to do keyboard related checks" now i whish to know if there a possible way to solve this..

Ps i tried other applications, games, and writing.. I didn't have any problem anywhere else but in minecraft

Answer (score 0):

Whoever told you LWJGL was at fault must be pretty inexperienced.

As both an LWJGL coder and also an experienced Minecraft plugin coder, I know that LWJGL cannot "not detect" keys if your computer thinks they are down.
Don't believe me? [Read through this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl/2.8.0/org/lwjgl/input/Keyboard.java) and you will see how it's impossible for keys to be "Not detected".

The issue will be either the computer, java, or the keyboard.

I think (and I believe others will agree) that **with the information you have currently provided**, LWJGL is in no way involved or at fault.